# AWS DataPipelineClient - listPipelines returns no records

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to access my AWS DataPipelines using AWS Java SDK v1.7.5, but listPipelines is returning an empty list in the code below.

I have DataPipelines that are scheduled in the US East region, which I believe I should be able to list using the listPipelines method of the DataPipelineClient. I am already using the ProfilesConfigFile to authenticate and connect to S3, DynamoDB and Kinesis without a problem. I've granted the PowerUserAccess Access Policy to the IAM user specified in the config file. I've also tried applying the Administrator Access policy to the user, but it didn't change anything. Here's the code I'm using:

```
//Establish credentials for connecting to AWS.
File configFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".aws/config");     
ProfilesConfigFile profilesConfigFile = new ProfilesConfigFile(configFile);             
AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider = new ProfileCredentialsProvider(profilesConfigFile, "default");

//Set up the AWS DataPipeline connection.
DataPipelineClient dataPipelineClient = new DataPipelineClient(awsCredentialsProvider);
Region usEast1 = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1);
dataPipelineClient.setRegion(usEast1);

//List all pipelines we have access to.
ListPipelinesResult listPipelinesResult = dataPipelineClient.listPipelines();  //empty list returned here.
for (PipelineIdName p: listPipelinesResult.getPipelineIdList()) {
    System.out.println(p.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check if there are more results - I've noticed sometimes the API returns only few pipelines (could even be empty), but has a flag for more results. You can retrieve them like this:

```
void listPipelines(DataPipelineClient dataPipelineClient, String marker) {
    ListPipelinesRequest request = new ListPipelinesRequest();
    if (marker != null) {
        request.setMarker(marker);
    }

    ListPipelinesResult listPipelinesResult = client.listPipelines(request);
    for (PipelineIdName p: listPipelinesResult.getPipelineIdList()) {
        System.out.println(p.getId());
    }

    // Call recursively if there are more results:
    if (pipelineList.getHasMoreResults()) {
        listPipelines(dataPipelineClient, listPipelinesResult.getMarker());
    }
}
```